# Why are Apache/php Headers in different case on Server vs local

Tags: php, apache, http-headers

Is there an Apache or Php setting that would change a header returned by `getallheaders()` from Capitalized to lowercase?

On my localhost it receives  an `Authorization` header but the same code returns `authorization` on the server. and the same client(Postman) is being used in both cases

Answer (score 0):

$headers = array_change_key_case(getallheaders(), CASE_LOWER);

Answer (score -2):

As per the `HTTP/1.1` spec `Field names are case-insensitive.`

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all. I asked about how the case is different in the result of getallheaders()